# fread: empty string ("") in na.strings is not interpreted as NA

Tags: r, data.table, na, fread, read.table

**How can I get `fread()` to set `""` to a `NA` for all variables including character variables?**

I am importing a .csv file where missing values are empty strings (`""`; no space). I want `""` to be interpreted as missing value `NA` and tried `na.strings = "" without success:

```
data <- fread("file.csv", na.strings = "")

unique(data$character_variable)
# [1] "abc" "def"      ""
```

On the other hand, when I use `read.csv` with `na.strings = ""`, the `""` are turned into `NA`s, even for character variables. This is the result I want.

```
data <- read.csv("file.csv", na.strings = "")

unique(data$character_variable)
# [1] "abc" "def"      NA
```

*versions*

- R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
- data.table_1.12.8

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with the following string `"a\nx\n\"\""` @GregorThomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't if your csv file looks like this

```
a,b
x,y
"",1
```

Note that whatever inside the `""` is treated as a string literal because `""` are the escape characters. In that sense, `,"",` in a csv file just means an empty string, but not a missing value (i.e. `,,`). I would consider this a good feature for consistency. This is also written in the section `na.strings` of the documentation of `fread`:

> A character vector of strings which are to be interpreted as `NA` values. By default, `",,"` for columns of all types, including type `character` is read
> as `NA` for consistency. **`,"",` is unambiguous and read as an empty string**.
> To read `,NA,` as `NA`, set `na.strings="NA"`. To read `,,` as blank string `""`, set `na.strings=NULL`. When they occur in the file, the strings in `na.strings` should not appear quoted since that is how the string literal `,"NA",` is distinguished from `,NA,`, for example, when `na.strings="NA"`.

On the other hand, you may notice that if the file looks like this

```
a,b
1,y
"",1
```

, then the empty string will be converted into `NA`. However, I think it's not a bug because this behaviour is probably a consequence of type coercion by the parser. In the `Details` section of the same document, you can see that

> The lowest type for each column is chosen from the ordered list: `logical`, `integer`, `integer64`, `double`, `character`.

So column `a` is first read as a character column and later converted into an integer one. The empty string is still read as is but coerced into an `NA_integer_` in the second step.

Comment: So in essence, fread() handles the "" differently than read.csv()?

Comment: Yup, I would say so.

Comment: Also, in my example the variable was a true character variable unlike c("",1), which in this case I'd want a numeric: c(NA, 1). Does the variable being truly character matter?

Comment: Yes. As pointed out by the documentation of `fread`, the character type is the highest type possible, so there is no type coercion to be performed on. You will just get an empty string in your resulting dataframe. On the other hand, if a possible lower type exists, the column will be further coerced into that type. That's why you may see c(NA,1)  even if the column is actually something like c("",1). fread does a type coercion like `as.numeric(c("",1))` silently for you.

Comment: I am happy to see people reading manuals so well. Yes, it is worth!