# fread: use of na.string and colClasses parameters

Tags: r, data.table, na, fread

I am not sure I understand the behavior of `fread` regarding empty strings. for instance

```
rawdata <- 'a,b\n"",""\nabc,2020-12-31 00:00:00'
fread(rawdata,na.strings=c("","NA"))
```

```
##      a                   b
## 1:                        
## 2: abc 2020-12-31 00:00:00
```

I was expecting NA, in the first row. Are my assumptions flawed?

In the same line, it is possible to have full control on the `colClasses` and the `na.strings` at the same time?

Say I want to read columns a and b as character.

```
rawdata <- 'a,b\n"",""\n1,2020-12-31 00:00:00'
fread(rawdata,na.strings=c("","NA"),
      colClasses=c(a="character",
                   b="character"))
```

I'm using data.table_1.13.6

### update

Part of the answer has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64798564/fread-empty-string-in-na-strings-is-not-interpreted-as-na)
It seems that `fread` uses a different parser that `read.csv` which might result into unexpected behavior.

One solution could be to replace all empty string by NA.
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516192/fast-way-to-replace-all-blanks-with-na-in-r-data-table). But I am not sure this process is faster than `read_csv`

Comment: `rawdata <- 'a,b\n,\n1,2020-12-31 00:00:00'` then empty will become `NA`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I don't have control on `rawdata` directly, I can control it only after `fread`

Comment: The first part is answered here: [fread: empty string (“”) in na.strings is not interpreted as NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64798564/fread-empty-string-in-na-strings-is-not-interpreted-as-na)

Comment: @Henrik many thanks for pointing this out. The post you refer to had escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

So once the fread parser is out of the way, then it is clear that `colClasses` and `na.strings` can be used simultaneously.

Note that trying to put empty quotes as `na.strings` does not do the job.

````
rawdata <- 'a,b\n"",""\n1,2020-12-31 00:00:00'
fread(rawdata,na.strings=c('\"\"',"","NA"),
      colClasses=c(a="character",
                   b="character"))
```


```
rawdata <- 'a,b\n,2020-12-31 00:00:00\n1,'
fread(rawdata,na.strings=c("","NA"),
      colClasses=c(a="numeric",
                   b="character"))
```

    ##     a                   b
    ## 1: NA 2020-12-31 00:00:00
    ## 2:  1                <NA>
````